# What returns select to declared variable when no row is selected?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I have following declaration in my sql procedure:

```
declare @my_var char(10)
select @my_var = ''
@my_var output

select @my_var = my_db.my_variable from dba.my_db
```

What is assigned to @my_var if there is no corresponding row?

Comment: Try it yourself `Select @my_var` :)

Comment: @TriV The problem is I can't

Comment: why cant you test it yourself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable does not get updated if a query returns no results; so will keep the value it was previously assigned (or `null` if it's not been assigned to).

You can see this for yourself by running the below code:

```
declare @my_var char(10)
set @my_var = 'a'
select @my_var = 'b' where 1=0
select @my_var --returns a

declare @my_var2 char(10)
select @my_var2 = 'b' where 1=0
select @my_var2 --returns null
```